# What to use so Geode native client pool doesn't hang if no locator found

Tags: gemfire, geode

If I turn off my Geode server and server locator, and then try and connect a client using:

```
PoolFactory poolFactory = PoolManager
    .CreateFactory()
    .SetSubscriptionEnabled(true)
    .AddLocator(host, port);

if (PoolManager.Find("MyPool") == null)
    p = poolFactory.Create("MyPool");
```

then the `poolFactory.Create("MyPool")` instruction simply hangs. What do I use to return the `Create` in this situation of no connection?

It ought to be something like [DEFAULT_SOCKET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/client/PoolFactory.html#DEFAULT_SOCKET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT) in the Javadoc but that doesn't exist in the C# native client...

`.SetFreeConnectionTimeout` doesn't return either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe PoolFactory::Create makes any synchronous connections, so I can't explain why it hangs. As this issue would require more back and forth you should post your question on the users@geode.apache.org mailing list.